# Save image from URL by paperclip using http basic authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

How can i save an image from an URL which is authenticated using http basic authentication, using paperclip?

I imagine the solution something like this:

```
require "open-uri"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :picture

  def picture_from_url(url)
    self.picture = open(url)
  end
end
```

But i need to put the credentials. How can i solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with the link http://blog.andreamostosi.name/2013/04/open-uri-and-basic-authentication/

```
require "open-uri"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :picture

  def picture_from_url(url)
    self.picture = open(url, http_basic_authentication: ['user', 'password'])
  end
end
```

And worked.